# MacBook Pro hard drive problems: Can it be hard drive cable?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware

My MacBook Pro 2009, (13inch, snow leopard), does not boot into OsX. I also have bootcamp windows, and I can boot into windows with no problem.

I pressed the D key while starting and made a Apple Hardware Test. The result was recognition of the following problem: 4HDD/11/40000004:SATA(0,0)

I tried booting with OsX installation disks and formatting the HFS partition, but the HFS partition does not SHOW UP! It only shows my other partitions (FAT and NTFS).
It's strange, because my bootcamp windows can see and read from my HFS partition.

1. Do you think that my hard drive is failing? if so, why I can still read the HFS partition from windows?
2. Some one was suggesting that it might be a hard drive cable problem. Does anyone else have any information about it? CAN it be really a cable probelm after all? I mean I can still use it under windows with no problem, if the cable was faulty, would this be possible?

Thank you

Comment: Try booting on the installation media and from there validate first the filesystem on the disk and then check the disk for bad sectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you experience a hard drive *(not rice!)* error, it's safe to assume the worst and take the initial precaution of backing up your data... Right now, before anything gets worse! Clone the whole drive and see if the clone boots.

Once you have a good backup, you can play with your old drive, attempting to reformat the entire device and see if that "fixes" the proble.

My experience leads metro suggest a real simple procedure: replace the drive before you can't get anything off it. Flakey hardware tends to fail at the worst possible time.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. Luckily my mbp boots normally with windows and I could back up everything.

Now I want to be sure if it is a Hard drive failure or the hard drive cable is faulty. So that I wont be wasting my money replacing the wrong part!

Answer (score 3):

The most overlooked part is the cable. i've worked in an Apple tech dept for the last 8-9 years and in the 13" MBP's i've seen Data cables/SATA cables go bad more often then the hard drive. could be from the thin factor of the drive or the drive itself causing the cable to short.

Best bet try the cable first before you mess with any data.

Comment: What are the symptoms of a bad hard drive cable? 
Isn't it true that when the cable fails, the hard disk becomes totally unaccessible?

Comment: I have MBP 13 that also suffered from cable failure. The symptoms were not so obvious, sometimes computer worked normally, then again it would not boot up anymore. The wanted to charge me almost 200 eur for new drive, diagnostics, OSX install but there was no replacement cable :) So I just ordered it off ebay and changed it myself. Still works like a charm.

Comment: Here is a link on diagnosing cables: basically divide and conquer with an external drive: http://www.macworld.com/article/2030013/advice-from-an-apple-tech-three-common-mac-fixes.html

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed how old this post is, but oh well. As b4d said, "The symptoms were not so obvious, sometimes computer worked normally, then again it would not boot up anymore." I have this same problem with my MBP10. Sometimes on boot when I go to the drive selection screen, I'll see the partitions and be able to load them and it'll work fine, but then in the middle of me doing something, I'll get the spinning gear in the middle of my screen (indicating that the computer is no longer reading the hard drive) and then I reboot and hold alt and it's gone. What I did was take my hard drive out and plug it in externally until I get a new cable.

Answer (score 0):

If you buy a replacement cable, it will be fixed yes but it won't last...

So, you'd better decide whether you still need your DVD rom or not. If not, what the heck, remove it and change it to a caddy wherein you can install your HDD or SSD into it.

- [https://www.amazon.com/Generic-Macbook-Unibody-Optibay-Superdrive/dp/B00GBYUS4C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GBYUS4C)